# How to dissolve inner polygons in a multipolygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, google-maps

I'm trying to get the boundary of a collection of zip codes. Here is my current sql:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology((ST_Union(geom)), .003)) as poly
FROM zcta5_data
WHERE zcta5 IN ('zipcodes')
```

Here, is what my result looks like. How do I get rid of the inner polygons?

[image]